# Javascript delaying prompts

Tags: javascript, prompt

Let's say I have 5 functions (it doesn't matter what they do).  In order to make the last function work, I need the user to input something, so I decide to include the following line:

```
var irrelevant = prompt("Question that you don't need to know")
```

The other four functions just log stuff to the console.  However, what's happening (and it doesn't really matter but, for stylistic reasons it's annoying me) is that the prompt command in the fifth and final function leaps up before any of the other functions have had a chance to log their info to the console.  Is there any way to delay the prompt command for just a moment or two so it doesn't do that?

Comment: If you add your js code, I may help you.

Comment: you really witness time travel?

Comment: We cannot help you with code we cannot see. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem, using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button).

Comment: There's no point.  I don't want the question to get sidetracked with inevitable nitpicks about the quality of the code.  I'm an absolute beginner and I don't have the time or the patience for that.  I have a prompt box.  I want it to wait a few seconds before it pops up.  That's it.

Comment: Then we have neither time nor patience to help you. Enjoy the silence. In the meantime search for setTimeout

Comment: @Nellington then it would appear that you have both missed the point or how SO works, and haven't spent much time here to see that the concerns you have don't really happen (much).  We cannot help with what we cannot see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem with some of my own code not too long ago. @mplungjan is pointing you down the right track. you could try putting your prompt into the following -

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var irrelevant = prompt("Question that you don't need to know")
}, 0);
```

This will add a 0 millisecond delay to your prompt but it can be enough to keep the prompt at bay until that line is reached.

Hope this helps.

Comment: that does not help for the last function to complete.